# How can I apply changes when clicking on an html checkbox in a django project?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

In my current django project I have the following model:

## Python 3.7.1 / django 3.0

```
class SampleClass(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And the following template code with 'sample' as an instance of the `SampleClass` above (only small snippet):

## HTML / django template language

```
<form action='#' method='post'>
     <input type='checkbox' name='is_active_checkbox' {% if sample.active %}checked{% endif %}>
</form>
```

Now, when the state of the checkbox is changed, I would like to immediately apply the change to the django database, without reloading the page (if possible). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You need to use Javascript - specifically [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) - to achieve this. There are lots of questions on stack overflow about the specifics of how to do this for different use cases.

Comment: Could you give a link please? Because I did not really find anything (probably wrong search query)

Comment: See https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/ for one approach to doing this.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/36281300/3955830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to start with a basic AngularJS, there are several functions that you can apply quickly, this option allows you to just add a CDN and keep working the frontend from Django. 
If you want to do something more robust, you can apply Angular 8+.  Here you should use Angular as a web server, and Django as REST Apis.

Here are some basic examples, where you can adapt it to your needs and play around with the theme. I've been working with Django for more than 6 years, but I started to integrate it with Angular less than a year ago (you can choose React, Vue, or whatever suits you best, but Angular was a comfortable decision for me)

I leave you here my Github with several examples of Django with all its code, there is also 1 pair with React.

[Github/Django](https://github.com/Nouvellie/django3/tree/master/apps)

Comment: please make sure to upvote my post if you think it can be helpful for other people